# How to create the sticky header using Angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to display sticky header.On scroll `header1`should be hidden and `header2` should show,How can i achieve this using **material**?

Here is my expected [**DEMO**](https://xrv5pw.axshare.com/#id=yrdg9w&p=home&c=1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you want? -> https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmplrqaolon?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.html

Answer (score 1):

The basic implementation of a sticky header is the same whether you use Angular Material or not - watch the scroll position of the page and hide or show the second header as desired. Here's a rough example using the Angular Material toolbar component for the header:

```
<div style="min-height: 150vh;"> <!-- Set minimum height to force a scrollbar -->
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <span>Header 1</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-toolbar color="secondary" style="position: fixed; top: 0;" *ngIf="scrolled">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <span>Header 2</span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

And in the .ts file:

```
scrolled: false;

@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll() {
    // Depending on the desired effect, you should probably only show the second header
    // if you've scrolled past the first header's height
    this.scrolled = window.pageYOffset > 48;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but its not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj?file=app%2Fsidenav-position-example.ts

Comment: Place `@HostListener('window:scroll', [])` directly above the function declaration for onWindowScroll instead of on the class declaration. You want to attach the listener so that onWindowScroll is invoked whenever the scroll event is detected.